# Unlimited option of Role in a Slash-Command

Tags: java, discord, command, discord-jda

With JDA, I am trying to develop a slash-command on Discord like this:

```
/command @role1 @role2 @role3...
```

I want to have an unlimited option of roles, but I can't find any solution to have an array of Role.
Have you an idea ?

My actual code:

```
commands.addCommands(
            new CommandData("command", "list of possible roles")
                    .addOptions(new OptionData(ROLE, "role", "the role"))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord does not offer any kind of variadic option types at this time. Your only hope is to use an option of type `STRING` and getting the mentions from it:

```java
commands.addCommands(
    Commands.slash("command", "list of possible roles")
         .addOption(STRING, "role", "the role")
);
```

This only works in `5.0.0-alpha.12` which added [getMentions().getRoles()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/commands/OptionMapping.html#getMentions()):

```java
public void onSlashCommandInteraction(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
  OptionMapping opt = event.getOption("role");
  List<Role> roles = opt.getMentions().getRoles();
}
```

Note: The string option still accepts arbitrary strings and other mention types. Be aware of this when handling commands this way.